# curl: (77) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) with self-signed CA

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssl, curl

I used `openssl` to generate a self-signed CA and the certificate on an AWS linux instance. And I imported the root certificate to a keystore, which is used by a back-end application to support HTTPS.

When I ran the following command to try to connect to the server,
`curl --cacert caroot.cer --capath ~/ca/ --user abc:123 https://localhost:9999`

I got the error `curl: (77) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)`.

I did the same steps on ubuntu, everything is working as expected.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

export PW=`cat password`

echo "generating the key pair and save to the keystore"
keytool -genkeypair \
    -alias test \
    -keystore test.jks \
    -dname "CN=localhost, OU=TA, O=S1, L=Toronto, ST=Ontario, C=CA" \
    -keypass $PW \
    -storepass $PW \
    -keyalg RSA \
    -keysize 4096 \
    -ext KeyUsage:critical="keyCertSign" \
    -ext BasicConstraints:critical="ca:true" \
    -sigalg SHA1withRSA

echo "self-signing the certificate where both owner and issuer are the same as test.jks"
keytool -export -alias test -file test_self_signed.cer -keystore test.jks -storepass $PW

echo "generating the certificate signing request(CSR) for test.jks"
keytool -certreq -alias test -keystore test.jks -file test.csr -storepass $PW

set RANDFILE=rand

echo "generating CA's private key and CA's CSR"
openssl req -new -keyout cakey.pem -out careq.pem #-config /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

echo "self-signing CA's certificate"
openssl x509 -signkey cakey.pem -req -days 3650 -in careq.pem -out caroot.cer -extensions v3_ca

echo 1234 > serial.txt

echo "signing test.csr using CA's certificate and CA's private key"
openssl x509 \
    -CA caroot.cer \
    -CAkey cakey.pem \
    -CAserial serial.txt \
    -req \
    -in test.csr \
    -out test_signed_by_CA.cer \
    -days 365

echo "adding CA's certificate to the keystore"
keytool -import -alias schedule1 -file caroot.cer -keystore test.jks -storepass $PW

echo "adding test's certificate signed by CA to the keystore"
keytool -import -alias test -file test_signed_by_CA.cer -keystore test.jks -storepass $PW
```

Comment: Try with a fullpath after `--capath` without a `~`. As strange as it may be some applications can not resolve the user home directory through ~. Of course check all permissions rights on this directory. Make sure you created symlinks to certificates with their hash value.

Comment: Thanks, got it work

Comment: Good if you resolved it, but please add an answer then on what worked so that you can accept it which will show this question as closed. And others will be able to learn and use your answer for their own needs.